# Why I am getting this error in my java program of file input/output?

Tags: java, file, input, output

I am not able to understand why this type of error is coming.

I don't really understand this topic. I am doing this because it's my practical submission in my college.

The error shown in the output:

[image: The error in the output]

```
>PS E:\Vedang\Java_Package> cd "e:\Vedang\Java_Package\" ; if ($?) { javac FileRandomIntegers.java } ; if ($?) { java FileRandomIntegers }

>FileRandomIntegers.java:9: error: constructor File in class File cannot be applied to given types;
          File inFile = new File("rand.dat");  
                        ^
 > required: no arguments
 > found:    String
 > reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

>FileRandomIntegers.java:13: error: no suitable constructor found for FileWriter(File)
               FW = new FileWriter(inFile);
                    ^
 >    constructor FileWriter.FileWriter(String) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; File cannot be converted to String)
 >    constructor FileWriter.FileWriter(java.io.File) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; File cannot be converted to java.io.File)
 >    constructor FileWriter.FileWriter(FileDescriptor) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; File cannot be converted to FileDescriptor)

>FileRandomIntegers.java:39: error: no suitable constructor found for Scanner(File)
               Scanner scanner = new Scanner(inFile);
                                 ^
>     constructor Scanner.Scanner(Readable) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; File cannot be converted to Readable)
>     constructor Scanner.Scanner(InputStream) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; File cannot be converted to InputStream)
>     constructor Scanner.Scanner(java.io.File) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; File cannot be converted to java.io.File)
>     constructor Scanner.Scanner(Path) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; File cannot be converted to Path)
> >    constructor Scanner.Scanner(String) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; File cannot be converted to String)
> >    constructor Scanner.Scanner(ReadableByteChannel) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; File cannot be converted to ReadableByteChannel)

>Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to get full output
3 errors
```

Code:

```
    import java.io.*;  
             import java.util.*;  
             class FileRandomIntegers  
             {  
                  public static void main(String args[])  
                  {  
                       FileWriter FW = null;  
                       BufferedWriter bfwr = null;  
                       File inFile = new File("rand.dat");  
                       try  
                       {  
                            int rand_int;  
                            FW = new FileWriter(inFile);  
                            bfwr = new BufferedWriter(FW);  
                            Random generate_rand = new Random();  
                            System.out.println("\nGenerating & Storing Random integers from 0 to 99..\n");  
                            for(int i=0; i<10; i++)  
                            {  
                                 rand_int = generate_rand.nextInt(100);  
                                 System.out.print(rand_int+"\t");  
                                 bfwr.write(rand_int+"\r\n");  
                            }  
                       }  
                       catch(IOException e)  
                       {  
                            System.out.println(e.getMessage());  
                       }  
                       finally  
                       {  
                            try  
                            {  
                                 bfwr.close();  
                            }  
                            catch(IOException e){ }  
                       }  
                       try  
                       {  
                            System.out.println("\nRetrieving Random integers stored in file 'rand.dat'..");  
                            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(inFile);  
                            while(scanner.hasNextInt())  
                            {  
                                 System.out.println(scanner.nextInt()+"\t");  
                            }  
                       }  
                       catch(NullPointerException e)  
                       {  
                            System.out.println(e.getMessage());  
                       }  
                       catch(FileNotFoundException e)  
                       {  
                            System.out.println(e.getMessage());  
                       }            
                  }  
             }
```

Comment: Do you have a custom class called `File`? `(argument mismatch; File cannot be converted to java.io.File)` indicates that there is

Comment: Unrelated, but this is funny: `FW = new FileWriter(inFile)`. Also unrelated, I'd consider using standard Java naming conventions.

Comment: https://qbprograms.blogspot.com/2015/09/s9p2.html

Comment: here's the link from where i got the solution..but this code is giving me error.

Comment: I don't understand this topic of file input/output.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the results from one of my tests.

```
Generating & Storing 10 Random integers from 0 to 99.
86 33 63 1 36 97 20 82 25 9 

Retrieving Random integers stored in file random.dat
86 33 63 1 36 97 20 82 25 9
```

I took your code and broke it into simpler methods that I could test individually.

I also used a `BufferedReader` to read the file, since you used a `BufferedWriter` to write the file.

Here's the complete runnable code I used.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Random;

public class FileRandomIntegers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new FileRandomIntegers().createAndProcessFile();
    }
    
    private Random random;
    
    public void createAndProcessFile() {
        this.random = new Random();
        File file = new File("random.dat");
        try {
            writeFile(file);
            readFile(file);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    public void writeFile(File file) throws IOException {
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
        System.out.println("Generating & Storing 10 Random integers "
                + "from 0 to 99.");
        for (int index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
            int number = random.nextInt(100);
            System.out.print(number + " ");
            writer.write(Integer.toString(number));
            writer.write(System.lineSeparator());
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
    }
    
    public void readFile(File file) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
         System.out.println("Retrieving Random integers stored in file " + 
                 file.getName());  
        String line = reader.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
            System.out.print(line + " ");
            line = reader.readLine();
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
        reader.close();
    }

}
```